# How to Get Calendar events in google sheet plus count free calendar days without meetings

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I was using this script but it is not working anymore. I would like to ask for help adding how many days I have available on my calendar without any meetings.

This is my sheet

[image]

```
function create_Events(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Calendarios");
var id_cal = sheet.getRange("B1").getValue();
var cal= CalendarApp.getCalendarById(id_cal);
var start_time = sheet.getRange("B3").getValue();
var end_time  = sheet.getRange("C3").getValue();
var events = cal.getEvents(new Date (start_time), new Date(end_time));
for(var i = 0;i<events.length;i++){
    var title = events[i].getTitle();
    var start_time = events[i].getStartTime();
    var end_time = events[i].getEndTime();
    var loc = events[i].getLocation();
    var des = events[i].getDescription();
    sheet.getRange(i+6,4).setValue(title);
    sheet.getRange(i+6,2).setValue(start_time);
    sheet.getRange(i+6,3).setValue(end_time);
    sheet.getRange(i+6,5).setValue(loc);
    sheet.getRange(i+6,6).setValue(des);
   }
   Logger.log("Events have been added to the Spreadsheet");
}
```

Comment: What's a free day?

Comment: This script has nothing that creates events

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
cal.createEvent(title, start_time, end_time, { description: des, location: loc });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it is not to create an event, it is to get the events created in google calendar. I have another script that creates events, but what I need to do is to get the events I had scheduled.

Comment: And yet it is called create_events

Comment: Error 
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'createEvent')
create_Events @ Calendario.gs:8

Comment: I can't see what is wrong.

Comment: I'd guess tthat you cal id is the problem